# Physical meaning of convolution

Tags: convolution, linear-systems

Suppose we have 2 signals x(t) and y(t) with $$ x(t)=\delta(t)$$
If $x(t)$ is the input to a linear and time invariant system $S$, lets say we get a X(t) as the output:

$$ x(t) \overset{S}{\rightarrow} X(t)  $$

If we have $y(t)$ as an input to the same system $S$, then we can predict the output of that system without knowing anything more about the system:

$$ Y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}X(\tau)y(t-\tau) d\tau $$

Which are different examples of convolution of 2 signals?

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/62233/what-does-the-convolution-mean-what-is-the-convolution-philosophy/62246#62246    Also this one:  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82405/why-is-sweeping-in-convolution-so-confusing/82407#82407

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very un-clear, but I *think* I understand what you're asking. It's already been asked, and answered. You can go straight to the [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4723/what-is-the-physical-meaning-of-the-convolution-of-two-signals), but I'd suggest you read through this first:

Let me make a couple of suggestions:

1. It is common practice to write *time-domain* signals such as your $x(t)$ with lower case letters, and *frequency-domain* signals with Upper case letters:

   - If $x(t)$ is your time-domain signal, then $X(f)$ would be your frequency-domain signal (note you can use any name as the dependent  variable, you'll sometimes see $x[n]$, $X[\omega]$, $X[k]$, etc.
     **The point is lower-case = time, UPPER-CASE = frequency**.
     $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$, while not *wrong* per-se, just look weird.
2. When talking about LTI (Linear Time Invariant) systems, it is also common practice to name the input $x$ and output $y$. Don't ask me why, it's just what you'll see over and over in textbooks and articles.

   - For your example, I'd write:
     $$x(t) \overset{S}\rightarrow y(t)$$

---

With that out of the way, if you input an impulse $\delta(t)$ to a LTI system, the output is called the **impulse response**, and is usually (again, most common) written $h(t)$.

$$\delta(t) \overset{S}\rightarrow h(t)$$

This impulse response **completely** characterizes the LTI system $S$. What this means is that once you know the impulse response, you can predict the output of $S$ to **any** input, through **convolution**.

Your statement:

> then we can predict the output of that system without knowing anything more about the system

is therefore only half-right: yes, you can predict the output of that system, but you DO know something about that system: its impulse response.

---

With that in mind, I'd re-write your statement and equation as such:

Consider a Linear Time Invariant system $S$, with impulse response $h(t)$. For an input $x(t)$, $S$ will output $y(t)$ as the result of the **convolution** of $x(t)$ with $h(t)$ (note you had a slight error in yours; it's ($x(\tau)$, not $x(t)$):

$$
y(t) = x(t) * h(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)h(t - \tau)d\tau
$$

Comment: yes you are correct I will edit